# Creating and splitting polygon in R

Tags: r, polygon, geospatial, spatial, geo

I'm trying to create 2 circles and then split them into 4 parts so that I get 8 sectors, then i want to attribute a value from 0-1 to each sector and colour the circle based on the value given to it.

Thus I have a vector

```
    ratio<-c(0.02,0.04,0.67,0.9874,0.134552,0.753,0.9754,0.23460)
```

Which contains the ratio of each sector and need to attribute these with the sector and colour sector based on these values.

I have been able to create the circle but its just one polygon, how do i separate the polygon into 8 sectors then attribute a value to it? or maybe create a numbering system to number the sectors ?

I have been searching online for a sometime now can't find the answer.

I have used the following code to create the polygon,

```
   circle1<-0
   circle2=0
   x1=0
   y1=0
   k=0
   y2<-0
   x2<-0
 for(l in 1:2){
  for(j in 1:4){
   for(i in 0:180){
    x1<-c(x1,l*cos(i*0.0087266462599716+k*180*0.0087266462599716))
    y1<-c(y1,l*sin(i*0.0087266462599716+k*180*0.0087266462599716))
   }
  x2<-c(x2,x1,0)
  y2<-c(y2,y1,0)
  x1<-0
  y1<-0
  k=k+1
 }
 circle1<-c(circle1,x2)
 circle2<-c(circle2,y2)
}

 circle3<-cbind(circle1,circle2)
 polymap(circle3,axes=T)
```

#below code is for creating the separate polygons

```
  polys <- SpatialPolygons(list(
   Polygons(list(Polygon(matrix(c(circle3[1:183,1],
       circle3[1:183,2]), ncol=2))),c[1]),
 Polygons(list(Polygon(matrix(c(circle3[184:366,1],
      circle3[184:366,2]), ncol=2))), c[2]) ))
```

I was advised to use splancs package.

I appreciate any suggestion.

I have been able to draw the polygons BUT still can't colour the plotted polygon based on the ratio vector. I need the colour to reflect the ratio.

Comment: can you explain the ratio vector?  What is the ordering of the sectors?

Comment: Well as each sector represents some land, the ratio is a vector which contains the ratio of land that is no diseased. 
The sectors are ordered anticlockwise.

Comment: I can now draw the polygon using code

 polys <- SpatialPolygons(list(
  Polygons(list(Polygon(matrix(c(circle3[1:183,1],circle3[1:183,2]), ncol=2))),c[1]),
  Polygons(list(Polygon(matrix(c(circle3[184:366,1],circle3[184:366,2]), ncol=2))), c[2])
))

this is only 2 polygons, but i can't somehow link the ratio to each polygon and colour it based on the ratio the sector has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility, using base R,

```
## Get circle points
circs <- function(radii, sectors=4) {
    radii <- sort(radii)
    rads <- seq(0, 2*pi, length=100*length(radii)*sectors)      # sample at these radians
    do.call(rbind, lapply(radii, function(r)                   # points for drawing circles
        data.frame(X=r*cos(rads), Y=r*sin(rads), 
                   sector=rep(1:sectors, each=length(rads)/sectors),
                   theta=rads, radius=r)))
}

## Draw figure
drawCirc <- function(radii, sectors, hues=NULL, densities=NULL, ...) {
    polys <- circs(radii, sectors)
    if (missing(hues)) {
        colors <- colorRampPalette(c("green","yellow","red"))(sectors*length(radii))
    } else 
        colors <- heat.colors(n=sectors*length(radii), alpha=hues)
    plot(polys[,1:2], type="n", ...)     # blank plot
    for (i in seq_along(radii))  {  # add polygons
        for (j in 1:sectors) {
            ind <- (i-1)*length(radii)+j
            color <- colors[ind]
            with(polys[polys$sector==j,],
                 if (i == 1) {
                     polygon(x=c(0, X[radius==radii[i]], 0), y=c(0, Y[radius==radii[i]], 0), 
                             col=color, density=densities[ind])
                 } else
                     polygon(x=c(X[radius==radii[i-1]], rev(X[radius==radii[i]])),
                             y=c(Y[radius==radii[i-1]], rev(Y[radius==radii[i]])), 
                             col=color, density=densities[ind]))
        }
    }
}

## Figures
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

## With no shading by ratio - not run
drawCirc(radii=1:2, sectors=4, main="No ratio")
drawCirc(radii=c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9), sectors=7, main="No Ratio, Varying Radii/Sectors")

## Density/Color by ratio
## ** You would need to make sure the ratio vector is in the proper order **
ratio <- c(0.02,0.04,0.67,0.9874,0.134552,0.753,0.9754,0.23460)
drawCirc(radii=1:2, sectors=4, den=ratio*50, main="Ratio by Density")  # by density
drawCirc(radii=1:2, sectors=4, hues=ratio, main="Ratio by Colors")    # heat map
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, and i take it would be easy to change from 1 circle to say 50 circles and from 4 sectors to 3600 sectors? (Sorry not in the lab at the moment)

Comment: well, you wouldn't be able to see any sectors if you made that many, I just ran it with 100 sectors and 10 radii and it works fine (kinda slow), but many more than that and its just a blur.  If you are running it with taht many polygons you may want to adjust the length of the `rads` vector in the `circs` function, so it doesn't get too long.

Comment: thank you, it seems to work for that as well, little issue, i tried to run it with number of radii>number of sectors but ti would stop colouring as soon as the number of radii is same as number of sectors any idea why that might be? I i have tied the code but i can't figure out what exactly is wrong with the code.

Comment: I realised what was wrong with the code, I changed the code so that the ind variable is now defined as ind<-ind+1 and before for loop ind set to 0. Works perfectly now, again thank you very much mate. 

The original code would jump by length radii thus not colouring in all the sectors.